# Distance between two search strings, in terms of words count in SQLite search?

Tags: sqlite

My SQLite database has thousands of articles, where each article is having huge text data. So whenever I search for two strings in the articles column of db, it gives irrelevant results. So, I prefer to sort results by the distance between the words I searched. For example, In string "Jhon went to USA today", the distance between "Jhon" & "USA" is 2. It could be implemented in C# after getting the results. But I prefer getting it in the query results itself.

In short, Is there any way to get distance between two search strings, in terms of words count in SQLite search?

Here is my code, without success!!!

```
var query = SELECT posts FROM table_name
WHERE post_body CONTAINS (NEAR(('John', 'USA'), 3))  //????
```

Here I tried to search within 3 words, but it would be better, if I could get the distance between the words, without giving distance argument myself, so I can sort ascending all the results.

Comment: It would be good if you will show some piece of code which you have tried. @MgBhadurudeen

Comment: Are you using the [full text search](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html) extension? What is CONTAINS and NEAR (the latter is a fts keyword, but not the way you're using it...)?

Comment: No. I read that article, but I could not get clear idea/code of what I need as mentioned here.